# Angular-UI dropdown doesn't open

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angular-ui

I'm generating `html` from `javascript` object. For example i have following object:

```
var e = [{'element' : 'button', 'innerHTML' : '<span class="dropdown-toggle">More<span class="caret"></span></span><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li>Menu item</li></ul>',
          'attrs' : {'class' : 'btn dropdown'}}];
```

And `js` function which generates following string `$scope.my_template`:

```
<button class="btn dropdown">
    <span class="dropdown-toggle">More
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </span>

   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>Menu item</li>
  </ul>
</button>
```

Than i'm trying to apply this template to the html page with:

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="my_template">
</div>
```

I see dropdown button in the page but when i'm clicking on it, it doesn't open.

Comment: A nice little jsfiddle or plunkr would help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the content of `my_template` is wrong.

I changed it, and its working fine for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/9VPMl35wzrUFkEWHFup5?p=preview

Now the content of `$scope.my_template` is:

```
<div class="dropdown">
     <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle" >More <span class="caret"></span></button>

     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
         <li>Menu item</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```